# Can't convert managed array to IReadOnlyList

Tags: arrays, c++-cli

The following C# code compiles and runs just fine:

```
private static IReadOnlyList<int> Foo()
{
    return new int[10];
}
```

However, the (supposed) equivalent C++/CLI code gives a compile error:

> Error C2440 'return': cannot convert from 'cli::array<int,1> ^' to 'System::Collections::Generic::IReadOnlyList<int> ^'

```
static IReadOnlyList<int>^ Foo()
{
    return gcnew array<int>(10);
}
```

The error message makes it sound as though C++/CLI has its own special array class that it's using under the hood, which is different from what C# does and which doesn't implement IReadOnlyList (or IList, or ICollection; IEnumerable does work, though). Is that correct? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently all you need to do is add an explicit cast:

```
static IReadOnlyList<int>^ Foo()
{
    return (IReadOnlyList<int>^)gcnew array<int>(10);
}
```

(I confirmed this does not blow up a runtime)